# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Startup.cs how to initialize class before adding it to service collection

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have requirement that before adding the class as Scoped to service collection, I want to set some properties.

How do I set some dynamic properties after reading it from config?

```
private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
     // read values from config
     ??PaymentService.Environment="DEV";??
     // plus some more dynamic values

     serviceCollection.AddScoped<IPaymentService, PaymentService>();
}
```

Or maybe if how can I retrieve an instance of the class after adding it to scope and then updating the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IPaymentService, PaymentService>(sp => new PaymentService() { Environment = "DEV" });
```